# Is there a way to debug into the cpq generate template process

Tags: cpq, quote-template

In CPQ Quote templates, we need to write xsl-fo code into the VF template and very often, it throws ambiguous error when previewing the document.

Is there a way to debug into it and understand what is happening or what is going wrong?

Or is there a way to find the generated xml file so I can try it myself?